# Invalid row key specified, data-load fixtures error Symfony 1.4

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4, fixtures

I have a problem with a symfony 1.4 setup :

I created the schema.yml:

```
BlogCategory:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    name: { type: string(255), notnull: true, unique: true }

BlogPost:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    category_id: { type: integer, notnull: true }
    title: { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    body: { type: string(255), notnull: true }
  relations:
    BlogCategory: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: category_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: BlogPosts }
```

(based on jobeet tutorial )

then it generated me the table schema.sql :

```
CREATE TABLE blog_category (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE, created_at DATETIME NOT NULL, updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE blog_post (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, category_id INTEGER NOT NULL, title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, body VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, created_at DATETIME NOT NULL, updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL);
```

which seems right to me.

And to finish I tried to add fixtures and load the data, my fixtures are as follows:

**data/fixtures/categories.yml:**

```
BlogCategory:
  design:
    name: Design
  programming:
    name: Programming
  management:
    name: Management
  administrator :
    name: Administrator
```

**data/fixtures/posts.yml**

```
BlogPost:
  initial_post_1:
    BlogCategory : design
    title: Initial post 1
    body: This post is an initial test number 1

  initial_post_2:
    BlogCategory : design
    title: Initial post 2
    body: This post is an initial test number 2
```

The php symfony doctrine:data-load command is generating me the categories but not the posts, so I tried :

```
php symfony doctrine:data-load data/fixtures/posts.yml
```

> Invalid row key specified: (blog_category) design, referred to in
>   (blog_post) initial_post_1

Any idea why I can't laod the posts ? I've already tried to delete the db re-generate etc...

Answer (score 0):

Okey so after many tests and `git reset --hard HEAD` to fix my datas, it seems that I had a problem with my BlogPost.class.php which contained an empty save() method override that was messing things up.

Plus, to rewrite data in the right way the command to use is:

```
php symfony doctrine:build --all --and-load
```

and not :

```
php symfony doctrine:data-load
```

Hope it could help anyone with the same problem !